# Paper.js not drawing to canvas

Tags: javascript, python, paperjs

I have designed a canvas that is created with functionality from the `pywebview` package. On this canvas, I attempt to use `paper.js` to draw a `Path`, then output the resulting rendered HTML to an image popup. The `Path` does not render on the page, although the same code seems to work on an [interactive snippet tester](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.17/S/dZAxawMxDIX/ivESHxxHktHQKVvpEMiQIcmgnkXPvcQ2OvWOEvLfI4VSmrT1ILC+56cnn22CE1pvNz1y29natjnofQQyAwOxeTIJJ1OgIDXrHBO7xXxeGynVnvZJhZjCn7LFvawAd/c6abizYiNnwLcTJh682d0m1+p7qL8xU+5xlY+ZvJkRhtkjgqIgf6Rf6FkC/ce2MXDnJai2L7ewGrSBENzjSkvdXEr1JVNSKL9jyw20HEd8gU/pydtVF4/BqdMP7RhxagLB5Cr56ldC6IsaD9bvDpcr) on the Paper.js website. This is my code so far:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import base64
import webview


def extract_image(width, height, path=[(100, 100)]):
    color = 'red'

    def callback(window):
        window.html = f"""
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/paper.js"></script>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="{width}" height="{height}"></canvas>
            """
        js_code = f"""
                var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
                paper.setup(canvas)
                var start = new paper.Point({path[0][0]}, {path[0][1]})
                var end = new paper.Point({path[0][0] + 1}, {path[0][1]})
                var path = new paper.Path({{
                    segments: [start, end],
                    strokeColor: '{color}',
                    strokeCap: 'round',
                    strokeJoin: 'round',
                    strokeWidth: 10
                }})
                path.add(new paper.Point(200, 200))
                paper.project.activeLayer.addChild(path)
                paper.view.draw()
                """
        print(js_code)
        print(window.evaluate_js(js_code))
        data_url = window.evaluate_js("canvas.toDataURL()")
        print(f"data url is: {data_url}")

        # Extract the base64 encoded image data from the data URL
        base64_data = data_url.split(",")[1]

        # Decode the base64 data and create a PIL image from it
        image_data = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_data))
        image = Image.open(image_data)

        # Display the image
        image.show()
        window.destroy()
    return callback


def extract_canvas_to_image():
    return webview.create_window('Hello world', frameless=True, hidden=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = extract_canvas_to_image()
    webview.start(extract_image(400, 400), window)
```

How can I get my Path to render properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should load paper.js with a cdn:

change:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/paper.js"></script>
```

to:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.17/paper-full.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This actually worked. Any idea why it changes things?

Comment: I think it's because that you doesn't have a localfile "paper.js", therefor pywebview can't loaded it.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense - I don't seem to have such a file. Thank you!